# Parse xml through jQuery get what is inside tags

Tags: jquery, xml, traversal

I have the code provided from the following link.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y469L21y)

I am trying to get the word "other" which is inside the  tags. In the best case the alerted value is undefined. I can't find it neither with the parent(), nor the siblings() or from its children().

```
other = xml.find("CustomerLoss High").next().html()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it.

I had to do:

```
other =  xml.find("Reputation").siblings().next().prop("tagName")
```